# Can't Import Number library error when importing arcade module

Tags: python, arcade

I'm getting the following error when I try to use the Python Arcade library. Any ideas?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\arcade_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import arcade
  File "C:\Users\Teacher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from arcade.application import *
  File "C:\Users\Teacher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\application.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numbers import Number
ImportError: cannot import name 'Number' from 'numbers' (C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\numbers.py)
```

Comment: `numbers` is a [standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html), but you masked it with `C:\Users\Teacher\Desktop\numbers.py`. Rename that file or delete it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. If you want to submit this as an answer I'll choose it.